# how to read text file from an android device's shared custom directory and show the contents of text file inside the textView

Tags: android

I am relatively new to Android Studio. I have already created an application that can write Passwords.txt files in the shared External storage directory inside documents folder as shown below
[snap shot taken not from emulator but from physical harware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5uBE.png)

Problems that I am facing:-

1. The application is saving Passwords.txt as it should inside the custom directory.
   But if I go inside the directory and delete Passwords.txt and uninstall the app.
   and recompile it then it throws the error. I don't know what's causing this
   [here is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax54f.png)
   But in reality there is no Passwords.txt file present in this directory as it's already deleted
   [this is the snap shot after deleting the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fArIQ.png)
   I am also not able to use same File name as Passwords.txt . If i change the File name then It functions normally
2. I want to read Passwords.txt and show the contents of Passwords.txt inside the textView but I can't figure it out how to do this

I already asked for permission in android manifest file

```
 <!--adding the user permission to access the external storage-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

here is my java file for mainActivity
Oncreate Function

```
package com.aditya.neomorphicui;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String File_NAME="Password.txt";
EditText editText;
TextView textView2;
Button open_file;
Button save_file;

//Strings related to file name and file directory
String FileName="";

//creating a variable to store data while writing
private static final int WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    save_file=findViewById(R.id.save);
    open_file = findViewById(R.id.open);

    //initialize two String variables for storing file name and file path
    FileName = "Passwords.txt";

    save_file.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M)  //checking our bhuild version of the os greater than marshmallow version
                {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

                        //show popup for runtime permissions
                        requestPermissions(permissions, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE);
                    } else {
                        //permission already granted; hence save data
                        //text typed inside the editText
                        String save = editText.getText().toString()+"\n";
                        saveToTxtFile(save);
                    }
                }//if statement closed

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input filed is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

checking and requesting permission

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_CODE: {
            // if request is canceled then result arrays are empty
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String save = editText.getText().toString();
                saveToTxtFile(save);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permission required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

saving data onto the file system by creating a directory and a txt file

```
private void saveToTxtFile(String save) {
    //get current Time for file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());

    try{
        //path to storage in the file system
        //File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        //getting the public directory
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        //create folder name "Brain_Trainer_game"
        File dir = new File(path+"/versus");
        dir.mkdirs();

        //File name
        //String Filename = "Password" + timeStamp + ".txt";
        String Filename = FileName;

        //creating new file
        File file = new File(dir, Filename);

        //FileWriter class s used to store characters in file
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        //save = String text data to be saved
        bw.write(save);
        bw.close();

        //Showing file name that was just created
        Toast.makeText(this,Filename + "is saved\n" +dir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //if anything goes wrong
        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `here is the error I am getting` Please mention your errors as text in your post.

Comment: And you are doing this on an Android 11 device.

Comment: https://youtu.be/idsUMiWjfnM

Comment: yes It is Android 11 @blackapps

Comment: You did not read my first comment?

Comment: Sam Chen your suggested youtube post was helpful thank you

Comment: @blackapps I included the screenshot because I couldn't find anything unusual while using debugging mode in android studio . And toast Message is the one throwing exception so I included a screen shot of the error that was coming through the toast message . I know I am complete noob to android dev . Please be patient with me sir .

Comment: I am patient. I already wait twenty hours for you posting errors as text. See my first comment. You should TELL which error you have.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Doucuments/versus/Passwords.txt:open failed:EEXIST(file exists) is the error i am getting.

Comment: You should put that in your post. I asked that yesterday.